# Spring @Autowired for setter methods vs non-setter methods

Tags: java, spring

According to [@Autowired javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html):

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired 
>   by Spring's dependency injection facilities. Only one constructor (at
>   max) of any given bean class may carry this annotation, indicating the
>   constructor to autowire when used as a Spring bean. Such a constructor
>   does not have to be public. Fields are injected right after
>   construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked. Such a
>   config field does not have to be public. Config methods may have an
>   arbitrary name and any number of arguments; each of those arguments
>   will be autowired with a matching bean in the Spring container.
>
> **Bean property setter methods are effectively just a special case of such a**
>   **general config method**. Such config methods do not have to be public.
>   In the case of multiple argument methods, the 'required' parameter is
>   applicable for all arguments. In case of a Collection or Map
>   dependency type, the container will autowire all beans matching the
>   declared value type. In case of a Map, the keys must be declared as
>   type String and will be resolved to the corresponding bean names. Note
>   that actual injection is performed through a BeanPostProcessor which
>   in turn means that you cannot use @Autowired to inject references into
>   BeanPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor types. Please consult
>   the javadoc for the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class (which,
>   by default, checks for the presence of this annotation).

My questions are:

1. What is meant by **config methods**?
2. And also, let's say I have a setter method with `@Autowired` and some arbitrary methods with `@Autowired`. I assume that setter method is invoked by spring automatically after the bean instantiation, while random-named `@Autowired` methods won't be invoked, am I right?
3. Also how does spring understand which `@Autowired` method should be invoked after the instantiation (setters), while others shouldn't? And how does this correlate with a statement from javadoc, saying that:

> Bean property setter methods are effectively just a special case of
>   such a general config method

One final question: **where I can read about it?** since spring documentation doesn't have any information on that and I wasn't able to find the exact logic used by spring in its javadoc.

Answer (score 7):

`@Autowired` annotation can be used with constructor, setter method or just any other method.
Whenever Spring finds `@Autowired` annotation it will try to find beans matching to method parameters and will invoke that method. If multiple methods (setter or non-setter) have `@Autowired` annotation, all will be invoked by Spring after bean instantiation.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that whenever spring sees 'autowired' on a method, it is obliged to invoke this method after the bean instantiation. Whenever spring sees 'autowired' on a field, it's required to initialize that property with appropriate bean. Whenever it sees 'autowired' on a constructors, it's obliged to invoke at least one of those constructors. So, basically in my Initial statement, I am wrong that non-setter methods annotated with 'autowired' are not to be called after the bean instantiation.

Comment: You hit the bulls eye!!

Comment: [dhblah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260894/dhblah) you are not exactly right about constructor. Only one constructor can carry @Autowired annotation. It's specified in javadoc you had attached.

Comment: @dhblah A bit late to the party here, but it's worth noting an exception to the rule you pointed out. Note that a ``@Lazy`` annotation can also be used in conjunction with ``@Autowired``. For example, if you use it with a field, both the field that's autowired and the bean that's autowired into that field need to be annotated as lazy for it to work (I believe). The effect is that Spring won't actually initialize the field after bean instantiation. Probably it will just initialize when that field is first accessed. See here for more: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation.

Answer (score 1):

A config method is a factory-like method, which in this case would get the paramaters autowired:

```
@Autowired
public SomeObject initSomeObject(Object1 o1, Object2 o2, ...) {
```

@Autowired merely ensures that Spring will (attempt to) provide the needed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Config-method in this context refers to methods that you would specify under `init-method` or `@PostConstruct`

Setter as you already know is like `setXXX`

So obviously there is no difficulty in finding which is which.
At the same time note that spring can not autowire based on parameter names.