# Spring @Autowire on non-setter methods

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I just came across some samples where the @Autowire is used on non-setter methods.

```
@Autowired
public void doSomething(MyType t){
     System.out.println(t);
}
```

1. how will i call this method ? like objectReference.doSomething(); does the parameter is not required while calling these methods ?
2. when do we use @Autowire on non-setter methods
3. can anybody share some samples on the same ?

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188262/spring-autowired-for-setter-methods-vs-non-setter-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring doc says clearly, `@Autowired` can be applied on Constructors, Fields, Setters and Arbitrary methods with arbitrary names and/or multiple arguments.

come to your questions, think of `doSomething(<>)` is an arbitrary method, which should be invoked by container not yourself.
[Have a look at this thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/77662-autowired-may-also-be-applied-to-methods-with-arbitrary-names-and-or-multiple-args)

Comment: Yes, that must be controlled by container, name can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR,METHOD,PARAMETER,FIELD,ANNOTATION_TYPE})
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Documented
public @interface Autowired
```

as we see from official docs @Autowired Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities. - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

But, how spring will know that you method is or is not a config method? When Spring finds @Autowired it will try to find beans matching to method parameters and will invoke that method.